CCFL(Cold-cathode fluorescent lamps) Power Source
I'm trying to understand how the inverter of a CCFL works. The CCFL was used as the backlight of an old Samsung TV.
It seems that the inverter output(secondary winding of the transformer) is a high voltage, high frequency (70kHz) square wave signal which is connected to one electrode of the lamp but the other end of the lamp is connected to a sine wave of the same frequency but with an amplitude of only 7Vpp. Why is the lamp being powered with two different signals






Are you sure CN2 goes to the electrodes of a lamp? It looks like it may be a monitoring circuit. What are JP9-JP11 and the pushbuttons?

Yes I'm sure, I added a new image with a zoom to the CN2 connector, it goes directly to the right electrode of the lamp. JP9-JP11 are jumpers (zero ohm resistors) I'm not sure but I think they put them there because there was a change in the pcb design, there are no push buttons in the image the white thing is a plastic separator between on layer of the LCD screen and the CCFL lamps.

There are current sensing shunts on one side, it is not another supply.

It doesn't look like it being powered by the 7vpp - that is a measure of the current flowing in the tube. After rectification the voltage at AA and AB are used to monitor the operation (maybe assist in brightness control?) of the backlight.

But CN2 is directly connected to the lamp and the schematic is showing an oscilloscope plot of two 7Vpp sine wave signals coming from there

@OmarRodriguez - those 7vpp signals are a result of the current flowing through the lamp. The source is the transformer generating the high-voltage drive to the other electrode.
